# Запятая после серии прилагательных с возможными причастиями перед подлежащим-субъектом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нашёл два таких примера на Нацкорпусе, [вот](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94eC0xL3NpcG92c2tpL3JvZG5hamEueG1s&dpp=5&format=html&g=i_doc&kwsz=5&lang=ru&level1=0&level2=0&level3=0&lex1=%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&lex2=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&lex3=%D0%BE%D0%BD&max2=10&max3=10&min2=1&min3=1&mode=main&nodia=1&out=normal&parent1=0&parent2=0&parent3=0&sampling=1&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod3=sem&sort=i_grtagging&spd=10&spp=50&sr=1&text=lexgramm) и [вот](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcG9zdDE5NTAvZmljdGlvbl9tZW0vYmV4dGVyZXZhL21hZ2lhXzAxLnhtbA%3D%3D&dpp=5&format=html&g=i_doc&kwsz=5&lang=ru&level1=0&level2=0&level3=0&lex1=%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&lex2=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&lex3=%D0%BE%D0%BD&max2=10&max3=10&min2=1&min3=1&mode=main&nodia=1&out=normal&parent1=0&parent2=0&parent3=0&sampling=1&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod3=sem&sort=i_grtagging&spd=10&spp=50&sr=1&text=lexgramm):

Умный, храбрый, красивый, знающий ратное **дело, он** принадлежал к числу тех рьяных, полных жизни и силы людей, которые во всяком деле, где нужна решимость, рвутся вперед с неудержимой силой, становятся во главе предприятия, увлекают за собой толпы людей менее решительных. [В. В. Сиповский. Родная старина. Отечественная история в рассказах и картинах (С XVI до XVII ст.) (1904)]

Красивый, умный человек, с красивой **женой, он** любил нас, а мы любили его и боялись. [Н. П. Бехтерева. Магия мозга и лабиринты жизни (1994)]

Чем объясняется обособление этой части? Оно верно?

Comment: Спасибо всем! Но где ссылки, товарищи?

Comment: Розенталь, [Обособленные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108), пункт 10.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр! Я, если честно, нашёл это у Розенталя после первого ответа, но пришлось постараться. Имел в виду, что хорошо было бы эти ссылки давать отвечающим в любом случае, по крайней мере Джиму, который ссылается на Розенталя.

Answer (score 2):

Одиночные и распространенные определения всегда обособляются, если стоят перед определяемым словом и это определяемое слово является личным местоимением. Вот два примера с распространенным определением и одиночным из Розенталя:
Убаюканный сладкими надеждами, он крепко спал.
Низенький, коренастый, он обладал страшною силою в руках.

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно. Прилагательные/причастия же не ставятся перед местоимениями (прописной буквой обозначены логические ударения):
*Добрый Он помогал нам.

Весёлые онИ танцевали.

Умные мЫ быстро решали задачи*.
Так никто не говорит.

А обособление и логическое ударение на последнем прилагательном проблему решает:
*Весёлые и вЫпившие, они пели песни.*
Но не так:
*Выпившие и весёлые онИ пели песни.*

Примечание: обособленные определения отличаются от необособленных, они должны быть самостоятельными, чтобы нормально звучало; обычно самостоятельные можно переставить в конец или подальше:
*Они пели песни, выпившие и весёлые.*
но не:
*Он помогал нам, добрый.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Просто хотел как бы продолжить предложение, поэтому "но" со строчной. А зачем? Чтобы оно продолжало примечание, которое началось со строчной. А так оно к нему не относится и висит в воздухе.

Comment: Тогда давай точку уберём) Строчная после точки — очень странно.

Comment: Не, то пример как предложение (не фраза), точка должна быть. Понимаю, что не идеально.

Comment: Если закавычить, можно поставить запятую и потом строчную. Не обязательно должна быть точка, она не элемент самого предложения.

Comment: Примеры в кавычках с новой строки не пойдут, даже Розенталь использовал для примеров курсив, да и в примере с новой строки точку пропускать глупо (в других примерах она же не пропущена). Не сказал бы, что точка не элемент предложения, она указывает на конец **текущего** предложения, не всех (здесь одно внутри другого). В общем, идеальный выход не найти, а мой — самый оптимальный.

Comment: Не согласен, что оптимальный. Ну вот, если одно внутри другого, то точку ставят только в конце всего предложения, иначе никак.

Comment: Здесь предложение разбито на фрагменты по строкам, нестандартный случай, рекомендации такого типа не подходят.

Comment: Точку в любом случае только в конце ставят всего предложения.

Comment: В правиле Грамоты речь только о конце предложения — точка сразу после кавычек. Здесь же середина.

Comment: Ну неправильно так!

Comment: А какое правило указывает, что неправильно? Даже у Розенталя нет про такое.

Comment: Ребяты, а почему бы вам не написать союз **но** с большой буквы, как в примере про выпивших и весёлых? Тогда всё будет в порядке.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец В первом комментарии указано, почему это не подходит.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой В кавычки может заключаться любой набор символов: *Напиши ".........." на заборе. Напечатай "..//ツ\\.." на бумаге.* К структуре предложения и его пунктуации это отношения не имеет. Просто в конце предложения повторять знак некрасиво, правила связаны с этим.

Comment: Вот такой пример: *Булгаков писал "Прошло некоторое время, и пелена воды перед глазами прокуратора стала редеть. Как ни был яростен ураган, он ослабевал." в своём романе "Мастер и Маргарита".* Чего первую точку в цитате оставить, а вторую убрать? Это нелогично. Может, обе точки уберём? Раз в первом предложении есть точка, то и во втором она должна быть.

Comment: Нет, поскольку продолжается предложение, точки в конце цитаты не должно быть, особенно перед кавычкой.

Comment: Ну где такое правило, про середину предложения?

Comment: В наших светлых головах оно! Точка знак конца предложения, а не часть цитаты.

Comment: *знак конца предложения* — да, так вот любого, внешним оно не ограничено. Откуда оно взялось в головах, по крайней мере в одной? Не надо выдумывать правила. Как было бы, на твой взгляд, лучше — другое дело. Маленькая точечка никому не хочет зла.

Comment: Мне эта маленькая точечка очень мешает.))

Comment: А другим — нет.

Comment: oleedd, если не хотите писать **но** с большой буквы, то где тогда запятая перед ним?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Нужна, но так будет некрасиво, потому что пример с новой строки, и тогда запятая как бы будет относится к примеру. Нестандартный случай. Здесь пришлось нарушить.

Comment: На твоей совести будет эта точка. ;)

Comment: Отсутствие запятой гораздо серьёзнее, чем это.

Comment: Ну правильно, нужна запятая, а точка — нет. Можно закавычить и поставить запятую. А почему ты без собачки пишешь?

Comment: Просто не хочется ставить запятую после точки, а точку не отдам)

Comment: А что, оповещение не приходит? Первому прокомментировавшему, не считая меня, должно приходить.

Comment: Раньше приходили, теперь перестали. Точку и запятую ставить вместе — верх абсурда.

Comment: Наверно, Александр сбил систему, прокомментировав. Она очень криво работает. Просто нажми на "отслеживать". *верх абсурда* — вот, поэтому и опустил запятую, ну и чтобы она не относилась к примеру, будучи вместе с ним на отдельной строке. Хотя вместе ставят — ";", но не одно за другим (логическая ошибка).

Comment: Я бы сделал так. Примечание как заголовок, сам текст с заглавной, после примера с выпившими точка, и новое предложение, начинающееся с "Но".

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Знаю об этом варианте, но мне так не хочется, мне больше нравится делать слово "примечание" частью предложения (как пишут "*Вывод:*" в школе). Пару раз уже так оформлял, но уже не помню где, а если менять здесь, то и там (где-то там) надо.