# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: Жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столом сильно расстроенная

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: *Жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столом сильно расстроенная.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны.

1. Без запятой. Словосочетание - часть сказуемого и принадлежит глаголу.
   *Жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столом сильно расстроенная.* Такие конструкции отличаются вариативностью падежа - словосочетание можно заменить на творительный: сидит сильно расстроенной.
   Об этом [Розенталь "Справочник по русскому языку"](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109), §18, пункт 2, подпункт 3) "связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым...".
2. С запятой. Словосочетание - определение подлежащего и принадлежит субъекту.
   *Жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столом, сильно расстроенная.* Розенталь "Справочник по русскому языку", §18, пункт 9 "Распространенное или одиночное определение обособляется, если оно отделено от существительного другими членами предложения..."

Как их отличить? Только контекст. Если это задание на экзамене с однозначным ответом - это так себе задание.

Comment: Не могу понять второй вариант. Там как присоединение. Такие определения ставятся в начале или в середине.

Comment: Да, оно в такой позиции не отличается от присоединения.

Comment: Согласен, с запятой — присоединительный член предложения.

Comment: Задайте вопрос в сервис. Хотя, в общем, даже у Розенталя указана разница.

Comment: Вы не понимаете это правило и слепо следуете ему. Проанализируйте интонацию, запятая обозначает паузу.

Comment: Нет. Розенталь вполне отчетливо указывает разницу между согласованными определениями и присоединительными конструкциями. Ваши слова об "интонации" - ваши индивидуальные фантазии.

Comment: Слушайте, уже 3 человека против вас, а вы спорите. В любом случае мы можем сделать "сильно расстроенная" присоединительным. Опишите разницу (между этим вариантом и №2, №1 трогать не надо), если считаете, что она есть.

Comment: Задайте вопрос в сервис. Так и быть, укажу вам параграф у Розенталя) И подчеркну нужное, обещаю!

Comment: Нет, разницу между двумя вариантами с запятой укажите. У Розенталя нет такого, потому что это то же самое. Там не рассматривается один и тот же пример с двух ракурсов.

Comment: Хорошо. Пишите вопрос в сервис.

Comment: Вопрос касается вашего ответа, и он адресован лично вам, такие вопросы здесь нельзя открывать.

Comment: Лично мне - это о моей жизни. Если вы не можете отличать согласованные определения от присоединительных конструкций и Розенталь никак вам не помогает, самое уместное спросить об этом на сервисе "Русский язык". Помогут те, кто отличает.

Comment: Да никто вас про это не спрашивает! Есть два абсолютно одинаковых по написанию варианта (оба с запятой). В чём разница? "Личный вопрос" и "лично вам" — это не одно и то же.

Comment: Задайте вопрос в сервис.

Comment: Это касается корректности вашего ответа (он не полностью корректен), такие вопросы положено задавать в комментариях, не призывайте нарушать правила. Вы не сможете ответить, потому что разницы нет.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Интонации как "фантазия"**

«*Ваши слова об "интонации" — ваши индивидуальные фантазии»* (из комментариев).

Интонация — это такая **невидимая субстанция**, о которой слышали многие,  но в которую мало кто верит (почти как в привидения). Но именно  интонация соединяет отдельные слова  и словосочетания в единое целое,  представляет само предложение  **как новое качество** и определяет в нем порядок слов и расстановку логических ударений.

Но пока  **правила с их формализмом и однозначностью** кажутся нам той единственной реальностью, которая может решить любые практические задачи. Да, обычно может, но не всегда.

**Парные варианты**  —  вот та тема, где одними правилами (без интонационного анализа) не обойтись. Но при этом мы всегда находимся **в поле правил**, которые  дают нам определенную свободу действий. Просто надо уметь этим пользоваться.

**2. Выбираем вариант**

[**Правило Розенталя,**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp1093) пункт 2 (3):

Не обособляются распространенные определения: связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого они входят.

(1) *Жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столом, **сильно расстроенная*** (обособленное определение).

(2) *Жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столом сильно расстроенная* (определение в составе сказуемого).

**Верным будет только первое решение**.

Вариант без обособления выглядел бы так: *Жена сидит за столом /сильно расстрОенная.* Это простое предложение, которое легко и естественно делится на две части: тема и рема по смыслу и две интонационные фразы, разделенные  произносительной запятой.  Но единственное полноценное ударение делается только **в конце фразы.**

Это обязательное условие для простого предложения. Добавление всего лишь двух-трех  слов-распространителей, изменение порядка слов ломает структуру, например: *Жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столом /сильно расстроенная.* Все предложение мы должны **прочитать скороговоркой как единое целое** (как бы на одном дыхании), подчеркнув ударением только заключительную часть. И вот это уже выглядит неестественно.

И тогда мы делаем вывод: **вторая часть должна быть обособленной**:  *Жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столОм,  // сильно расстрОенная.* **Контекст для решения не нужен.**

**3. О присоединительных и обособленных членах**

Определительные обороты могут обособляться в любой позиции, но при этом они входят **в основное содержание предложения и присоединительными не являются.**

Присоединение — это **особая тема**, в том числе по содержанию (дополнительные замечания, иногда значительно распространенные, использование  более сильных знаков и т.д.).

Мы можем обособлять различные конструкции с присоединительным значением **с помощью запятой**, интонация при этом не отличается от обычной интонации обособления. Особая присоединительная интонация используется при постановке более сильных знаков, например тире.

Но в нашем случае **нет присоединения** ни по семантике, ни по интонации — обособленный оборот входит в основную тему.

4. **Приложение (примеры парных вариантов)**

При решении задачи   следует ориентироваться на различные факторы: распространенность оборота, порядок слов, но в конечном итоге проверку следует делать с помощью интонации.

*Однажды дед вернулся с работы довольный и озабоченный. Однажды дед  вернулся с работы чуть раньше, **довольный и озабоченный**.*

*Дети отправились в путь бодрые и весёлые. Через некоторое время дети уже отправились в путь, **бодрые и весёлые**.*

Comment: Первый пункт понравился. С неестественностью можно согласиться. Но и вариант с запятой тоже неестественный. Да потому что сам порядок слов неестественный (играются с языком и даже не могут придумать нормальный пример). Интонационная разница между двумя абсолютно одинаковыми по написанию вариантами (присоединение и обособленное определение) есть? Если да, то в чём она заключается?

Comment: 1. Вариант с обособление естественен с точки зрения интонации, а вот семантика зависит от контекста. Представьте,что вы видите только фрагмент картины и беретесь обсуждать ее художественные достоинства. Это было бы странно. 2. Присоединительная интонация  имеет характерные особенности в частных случаях (например, при использовании тире), но это не так заметно при постановке запятой, например:  "И тогда он вышел, молча".  Здесь  мы можем  увеличить паузу и понизить тон на предыдущем слове (как в конце предложения), но графически это не обозначено.

Comment: Семантику не трогаем, там всё чисто. Сам порядок слов неестественный, да хочется слово добавить, чтобы нормально звучало: *Жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столом, она сильно расстроенная.* То есть в данном случае оно от присоединения не отличается по интонации (другие случаи не рассматриваем). В ваших примерах явное присоединение.

Comment: Это не присоединение ни по интонации, ни по семантике. Определительный оборот может занимать любую позицию в предложении (это выбор автора по контексту.  По грамматике отношения полупредикативные (оборот как аналог придаточного определительного предложения).  Для того и существуют обороты, что он более компактные, чем сложное предложение с двумя полноценными основами.

Comment: Но мы можем сделать присоединение, добавив оборот в конце. Интонационной разницы нет. Всё отчётливее понимаю это. Слово "столом" должно читаться как конец предложения, как и при присоединении.

Comment: Что присоединение, что обособленное определение. Здесь нет двух интонационных вариантов, интонация совпадает, как и написание.

Comment: Весь текст возьмите для ясности понимания.  Интонация у вас совпадает? Неудивительно, оборот-то распространенный. Поэтому тире поставьте,  если присоединение хотите.  И будет вам тогда еще большее понимание, счастье  и нирвана.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это просто неудачно придуманный пример (он не звучит нормально с таким порядком слов, а ваши звучат). А раз интонация совпадает, то и обособленное определение с присоединением совпадает.

Comment: oleedd, пусть будет все, как вы хотите))   И это мое пожелание всем участникам форума))

Comment: Не, ну а разве не так? Обособление в такой позиции не всегда удачно, здесь ещё и стилистику надо учитывать. Ой-ой, точно, здесь ещё играет роль фактор, который обнаружил. См. в конце моего ответа: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467943 Не зря у вас в примерах два определения.

Comment: Все, Олидик, я пас.  Не надо меня больше допрашивать..  Вы уж тут за меня поработайте, ага? До новых встреч!